# angular.element('#home') returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router and angularJS 1.4, i want to access a controller scope. 
THe first time i used angular.element('#home').scope().HomeCtrl and it worked fine.
The second time it didn't even return the '#home' element, you can find more details int the code snippet.

What's causing this behaviour ?

```
            var modifyBoardState = {
            name: "root.main.home.modify",
            url: "/modify/{boardId}",
            authenticate: true,
            onEnter: ['DataStore', 'board', '$state', function(DataStore, board, $state) { 
                var vm = angular.element('#home').scope().vm; // This one works fine.
                vm.currentBoard.name = board.getName();
                vm.currentBoard.colorIndex = board.getColorIndex();
                vm.currentBoard.iconIndex = board.getIconIndex();
                vm.colorArray[vm.getPaletteColors()[board.getColorIndex()]] = 'active';
                vm.iconArray[vm.getPaletteIcons()[board.getIconIndex()]] = 'active';
                vm.addBoard = function() {
                    board.modify(vm.currentBoard.name, vm.currentBoard.colorIndex, vm.currentBoard.iconIndex);
                    $state.go('root.main.home');
                };
            }],
            onExit: ['$mdMenu', function($mdMenu) {
                $mdMenu.hide();
                // This one returns undifined.
                var vm = angular.element('#home').scope().vm;
            }],
            resolve: {
                board: ['DataStore', '$stateParams', function(dataStore, $stateParams) {
                    return dataStore.fetchBoard($stateParams.boardId)
                        .then(function(board) {
                            return board;
                        });
                }]
            }
        };
```

Comment: Accessing DOM elements from controller is not reliable and will not work. You are doing it wrong. Consider services for sharable data.

Comment: Try putting a `debugger` statement as the first line of `onExit` and reload the page while DevTools open then eval and compare.

Comment: i did and it returned undefined. I insist that in the onEnter section, it worked, but in the onExit section, it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data in between states you could use $stateProvider, and use the data param to pass your DOM elements.

Comment: I just want to access the scope of a spécific controller that's all. Look at the code, i said it worked on the first case but not the second one.